# Limiting dependency resolution to custom repository

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have the following custom repository URL for a plugin that I'm trying to load in my application:

`https://server.com/artifactory/plugins-release-local/abc/pluginXYZ/r181/pluginXYZ-r181.jar`

In my `build.gradle` file:

```
...
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core' }
    //custom Artifactory repository
    maven { url 'https://server.com/artifactory/plugins-release-local' }
}
...
dependencies {
    compile "abc:pluginXYZ:r181"
}
```

Next, attempt to compile:

```
me@workstation ~/my_app
$ grails compile
[buildinfo] Not using buildInfo properties file for this build.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.906 secs
Error |
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information
```

Next, attempt to diagnose dependency issues:

```
me@workstation ~/my_app
$ ./gradlew dependencies --info | grep missing
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/abc/pluginXYZ/r181/wetkit-r181.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/abc/pluginXYZ/r181/wetkit-r181.jar]
```

In this case, `pluginXYX` will never be found on `repo.grails.org`. How can I limit the resolution to my custom Artifactory repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I essentially reworked the maven closure and provided an artifactUrls attribute.

```
...
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        artifactUrls "https://server.com/artifactory/plugins-release-local"
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "abc:pluginXYZ:r181"
}
...
```

Also: [Example 23.30. Adding additional Maven repositories for JAR files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)